# Screen doesnt show before onResume

Tags: android, onresume

I am trying to show a waiting screen in my app while it's trying to connect my server. For some reason, the screen shows only in the middle of the while loop and sometimes even after the while loop has done its work. Also, even after the while loop gets to its end the code after it doesn't executed (it doesn't print the values). Does anyone know how to fix it?

This is the code:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final long SEC_IN_MS = 1000;
public static final int CONNECT_LOOP_TIME = 5; //In seconds
DataSender dataSender = new DataSender();
DataCenter dataCenter = DataCenter.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

    dataSender.execute();
    dataCenter.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    moveToMenu();
}

public void moveToMenu() {
    long loopStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean didConnect = false;
    while(!didConnect &&
            System.currentTimeMillis()-loopStartTime <= SEC_IN_MS*CONNECT_LOOP_TIME) {
        //Wait until connected or 5 seconds pass
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-loopStartTime);
        if(dataCenter.getRespond().equals(dataCenter.okMsg())) {
            didConnect = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("111111111111111111");
    System.out.println(didConnect);
    if(didConnect) {
        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextIntent);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("OOPS");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't just block the UI thread whilst waiting. Instead you should probably poll your response.

Comment: @HenryTwist I need to check the response for 5 seconds because sometimes it takes time to get it over the internet. how can I do so without blocking the "onResume"?

Comment: Well you're obviously receiving a response somewhere so you probably wouldn't need to 'wait' for it in this way at all. However if you really can't, then you could poll it instead of blocking, check it every second or so.

Comment: @HenryTwist well you are right, but I want to give a solution also when the server he contacts with is down or something. I will try to do so with a thread but if you have another solution or you understand why the activity doesn't show before the onResume I would like to hear

Comment: Why show something before OnResume(), this seems a wrong expectation altogether, you can just show a progress bar till you get a response back from your server you can hide the progress bar and show your content, as simple as that, I think you are making your situation little complicated by your self.